# Android Live Video Processing Using Open GL

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, camera, surfaceview

I am trying to do live video processing on Android 4.03 using OpenGL ES. So for example i would like to get a live video feed and display it on the screen with custom modifications, such as only drawing the red component of the video.

I have no trouble establishing a camera connection and displaying it into a normal view. I am also able to do a moderate amount of open gl.

What i am having difficulty with is getting the live video feed into open gl so i can process it.

This is the best link i have so far.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE[1-25]